# check if a variable contains img tagname

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a variable which stores user html input, this input might be a text or an image. I want to check if the user have entred an image or a simple text

example of user entry

```
this.userEntries = <p> < img  src=" nature.png"></p>

txtOrImg: function () {
// expected logic 
if userEntries includes tagname('img') return ... else return ...
}
```

Comment: You mean... `this.userEntries = '<p><img src="nature.png"></p>'`

Comment: yes, that was a hard coded example of user entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**DOMParser()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/DOMParser) and its [parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) Method. Then traverse it using [Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get a desired child Element

```js
const data = `<p><img src="nature.png"></p>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html");
const img = doc.querySelector("img");

if (img) {
  console.log("Has image!", img);
} else {
  console.log("No image");
}
```

For multiple images use [Element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
const data = `<p>
  <img src="nature.png">
  <img src="buildings.png">
</p>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html");
const imgs = doc.querySelectorAll("img");

imgs.forEach(img => {
  console.log(`Found image: ${img.src}`);
});
```

Comment: I expected the use of `getElementsByTagName(tagName) ` ;)

Comment: @chafchr not a huge difference tbh, will achieve the same result.

Comment: yeah @kissu I have tested it with getElementsByTagName too

Comment: @chafchr getElementsByTagName returns a live HTMLCollection, whilst querySelector and querySelectorAll return a static NodeList. Personally I use always the latter two for their selector powers, but it all depends on the task.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan is there a way to identify an appended img ? or at least get the list of it ?

Comment: @chafchr sorry, I don't understand the question. Please clarify

Comment: I mean what if my user has edited his input and added a second img, can I precise which image has been appended ? or so can I get the length of that node list (using `querySelector` ?

Comment: @chafchr added an example for multiple images

Comment: thanks a lot. what about retreiving the querySelectorAll length `doc.querySelectorAll("img").length;` would it be the correct property ?

Comment: @chafchr yes. `imgs.length`